# Where to store AES key on Arduino board

Tags: c++

I'm working with this library [AES lib](http://utter.chaos.org.uk/%7Emarkt/AES-library.zip) so everything works I can encrypt/decrypt data. But now I'd like to know what is the best way to store my `aes private key` ? My boars is a personnal board build with an `samd21 cortex M0+` my board doesn't have the possibility to connect with the extern world, like ethernet or ble, wifi.

I've only one possibility is to store the key in my program but what is the best way? Obfuscate my key? I know there is no perfect and secure solution if my key is store in my program, but what is the best solution ? Maybe is it possible to put my key when I upload my sketch in compiler option and store it in emulate eeprom?

Comment: I'm no expert in samd controllers, but I don't think it makes any difference for security if you store in program space or EEPROM (especially emulated)

Comment: @chrisl Yes sure you've right, but I'am little bit lost, about how/where to store my private key

Comment: For program space you could just write in as a variable in your code (you can even put it in a different file than the main code and include that file).

Comment: @chrisl Yes but if I write my key in a variable, it would be easy after a disassembly to get my key no?

Comment: Just store it in your code as a "const" and turn on "code protection" in the chip's configuration bits.

Comment: Your key will be in the program space no matter what you do, so someone reading the program space would easily get it. Majenko is right with the code protection. Remove any bootloader and enable code protection, which prevents an attacker to read the program space. Though I'm not sure, how exactly this is done on samd controllers

Comment: what is being encrypted if there's no connection to the outside world?

Comment: @dandavis I encrypt data log about system in SD card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can really do with your key is to just store it in your code. It makes no difference if that is as a `const` variable or stashed in emulated EEPROM.

The real question is not how to store it but how to stop someone reading it. Most microcontrollers (and the SAMD21 is no exception) have "code protection" facilities - settings you can enable in the chip's configuration (or "fuse") bits to prevent the flash being read by any external debugger or programmer.  By enabling these bits (check the datasheet for your chip) you will prevent people being able to read the flash containing your key no matter *how* you store it.

Comment: Does enabled fuse prevent rewriting the flash using OTA where the new binary is downloaded and swapped with old one?

Comment: No idea. The datasheet should tell you if flash write is inhibited in software or not. Probably not.